# Cómo puedo conectarme a un proxy con usuario y contraseña con wininet

Tags: c#, proxy

Llevo mucho tiempo con esto sin éxito. Encuentro buen código para conectar la conexión de un proceso a Internet a través de un proxy, pero lo que no consigo es hacerlo con un proxy que me pida usuario y contraseña. La cuestión es que no entiendo en absoluto el código que estoy utilizando, por lo que soy incapaz de modificarlo con éxito.

¿Podéis darme el código que necesito para añadir usuario y contraseña en el siguiente código? Muchas gracias de antemano.

{

```
    public static class WinInetInterop
{       
    private static string nombrePrograma = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name; //extrae el nombre de la aplicación

    [DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern IntPtr InternetOpen(
        string lpszAgent, int dwAccessType, string lpszProxyName,
        string lpszProxyBypass, int dwFlags);

    [DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool InternetCloseHandle(IntPtr hInternet);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    private struct INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST
    {
        public int Size;

        // The connection to be set. NULL means LAN.
        public System.IntPtr Connection;

        public int OptionCount;
        public int OptionError;

        // List of INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTIONs.
        public System.IntPtr pOptions;
    }
    private enum INTERNET_OPTION
    {
        // Sets or retrieves an INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST structure that specifies
        // a list of options for a particular connection.
        INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION = 75,

        // Notify the system that the registry settings have been changed so that
        // it verifies the settings on the next call to InternetConnect.
        INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED = 39,

        // Causes the proxy data to be reread from the registry for a handle.
        INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH = 37

    }

    private enum INTERNET_PER_CONN_OptionEnum
    {
        INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS = 1,
        INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_SERVER = 2,
        INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_BYPASS = 3,
        INTERNET_PER_CONN_AUTOCONFIG_URL = 4,
        INTERNET_PER_CONN_AUTODISCOVERY_FLAGS = 5,
        INTERNET_PER_CONN_AUTOCONFIG_SECONDARY_URL = 6,
        INTERNET_PER_CONN_AUTOCONFIG_RELOAD_DELAY_MINS = 7,
        INTERNET_PER_CONN_AUTOCONFIG_LAST_DETECT_TIME = 8,
        INTERNET_PER_CONN_AUTOCONFIG_LAST_DETECT_URL = 9,
        INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS_UI = 10,
        INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY_USERNAME = 43,
        INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY_PASSWORD = 44
}
    private const int INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT = 1;  // direct to net
    private const int INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG = 0; // read registry
                                                        /// <summary>
                                                        /// Constants used in INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTON struct.
                                                        /// </summary>
    private enum INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONN_FLAGS
    {
        PROXY_TYPE_DIRECT = 0x00000001,   // direct to net
        PROXY_TYPE_PROXY = 0x00000002,   // via named proxy
        PROXY_TYPE_AUTO_PROXY_URL = 0x00000004,   // autoproxy URL
        PROXY_TYPE_AUTO_DETECT = 0x00000008   // use autoproxy detection
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used in INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION.
    /// When create a instance of OptionUnion, only one filed will be used.
    /// The StructLayout and FieldOffset attributes could help to decrease the struct size.
    /// </summary>
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    private struct INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_OptionUnion
    {
        // A value in INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONN_FLAGS.
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public int dwValue;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public System.IntPtr pszValue;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ftValue;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION
    {
        // A value in INTERNET_PER_CONN_OptionEnum.
        public int dwOption;
        public INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_OptionUnion Value;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets an Internet option.
    /// </summary>
    [DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool InternetSetOption(
        IntPtr hInternet,
        INTERNET_OPTION dwOption,
        IntPtr lpBuffer,
        int lpdwBufferLength);

    /// <summary>
    /// Queries an Internet option on the specified handle. The Handle will be always 0.
    /// </summary>
    [DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true,
        EntryPoint = "InternetQueryOption")]
    private extern static bool InternetQueryOptionList(
        IntPtr Handle,
        INTERNET_OPTION OptionFlag,
        ref INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST OptionList,
        ref int size);

    /// <summary>
    /// Set the proxy server for LAN connection.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool SetConnectionProxy(string proxyServer)
    {

        IntPtr hInternet = InternetOpen(nombrePrograma, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, null, null, 0);

        //// Create 3 options.
        //INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION[] Options = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION[3];

        // Create 4 options.
        int opciones = 4;

        INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION[] Options = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION[opciones];

        // Set PROXY flags.
        Options[0] = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION();
        Options[0].dwOption = (int)INTERNET_PER_CONN_OptionEnum.INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS;
        Options[0].Value.dwValue = (int)INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONN_FLAGS.PROXY_TYPE_PROXY;

        // Set proxy name.
        Options[1] = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION();
        Options[1].dwOption = (int)INTERNET_PER_CONN_OptionEnum.INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_SERVER;
        Options[1].Value.pszValue = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(proxyServer);

       //Set username.
        Options[2] = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION();
        Options[2].dwOption = (int)INTERNET_PER_CONN_OptionEnum.INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY_USERNAME;
        Options[2].Value.pszValue = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAuto(username);

        // Set password.
        Options[3] = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION();
        Options[3].dwOption = (int)INTERNET_PER_CONN_OptionEnum.INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY_PASSWORD;
        Options[3].Value.pszValue = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAuto(password);

        // Allocate a block of memory of the options.
        System.IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(Options[0]) + Marshal.SizeOf(Options[1]) + Marshal.SizeOf(Options[2]) + Marshal.SizeOf(Options[3]));                    
        System.IntPtr current = buffer;

        // Marshal data from a managed object to an unmanaged block of memory.
        for (int i = 0; i < Options.Length; i++)
        {
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(Options[i], current, false);
            current = (System.IntPtr)((int)current + Marshal.SizeOf(Options[i]));
        }

        // Initialize a INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST instance.
        INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST option_list = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST();

        // Point to the allocated memory.
        option_list.pOptions = buffer;

        // Return the unmanaged size of an object in bytes.
        option_list.Size = Marshal.SizeOf(option_list);

        // IntPtr.Zero means LAN connection.
        option_list.Connection = IntPtr.Zero;

        option_list.OptionCount = Options.Length;
        option_list.OptionError = 0;
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(option_list);

        // Allocate memory for the INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST instance.
        IntPtr intptrStruct = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(size);

        // Marshal data from a managed object to an unmanaged block of memory.
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(option_list, intptrStruct, true);

        // Set internet settings.
        bool bReturn = InternetSetOption(hInternet, INTERNET_OPTION.INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION, intptrStruct, size);

        // Free the allocated memory.
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(buffer);
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(intptrStruct);
        InternetCloseHandle(hInternet); //¿Esto lo cierra?

        // Throw an exception if this operation failed.
        if (!bReturn)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(" Set Internet Option Failed!");
        }

        return bReturn;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Backup the current options for LAN connection.
    /// Make sure free the memory after restoration. 
    /// </summary>
    private static INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST GetSystemProxy()
    {

        // Query following options. 
        INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION[] Options = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION[3];

        Options[0] = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION();
        Options[0].dwOption = (int)INTERNET_PER_CONN_OptionEnum.INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS;
        Options[1] = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION();
        Options[1].dwOption = (int)INTERNET_PER_CONN_OptionEnum.INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_SERVER;
        Options[2] = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION();
        Options[2].dwOption = (int)INTERNET_PER_CONN_OptionEnum.INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_BYPASS;

        // Allocate a block of memory of the options.
        System.IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(Options[0])
            + Marshal.SizeOf(Options[1]) + Marshal.SizeOf(Options[2]));

        System.IntPtr current = (System.IntPtr)buffer;

        // Marshal data from a managed object to an unmanaged block of memory.
        for (int i = 0; i < Options.Length; i++)
        {
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(Options[i], current, false);
            current = (System.IntPtr)((int)current + Marshal.SizeOf(Options[i]));
        }

        // Initialize a INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST instance.
        INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST Request = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST();

        // Point to the allocated memory.
        Request.pOptions = buffer;

        Request.Size = Marshal.SizeOf(Request);

        // IntPtr.Zero means LAN connection.
        Request.Connection = IntPtr.Zero;

        Request.OptionCount = Options.Length;
        Request.OptionError = 0;
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(Request);

        // Query internet options. 
        bool result = InternetQueryOptionList(IntPtr.Zero,
            INTERNET_OPTION.INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION,
            ref Request, ref size);
        if (!result)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(" Set Internet Option Failed! ");
        }

        return Request;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Restore the options for LAN connection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool RestoreSystemProxy()
    {

        IntPtr hInternet = InternetOpen(miniYo, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, null, null, 0);

        INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST request = GetSystemProxy();
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(request);

        // Allocate memory. 
        IntPtr intptrStruct = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(size);

        // Convert structure to IntPtr 
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(request, intptrStruct, true);

        // Set internet options.
        bool bReturn = InternetSetOption(hInternet, INTERNET_OPTION.INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION, intptrStruct, size);

        // Free the allocated memory.
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(request.pOptions);
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(intptrStruct);

        if (!bReturn)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(" Set Internet Option Failed! ");
        }

        // Notify the system that the registry settings have been changed and cause
        // the proxy data to be reread from the registry for a handle.
        InternetSetOption(hInternet, INTERNET_OPTION.INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
        InternetSetOption(hInternet, INTERNET_OPTION.INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH, IntPtr.Zero, 0);

        InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);

        return bReturn;
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: No conozco esa libreria, pero luego de mirar tu codigo, veo que estas mandando un array de opciones, y usas un enum para declarar cada opcion.. y una de ellas es el user y otra el password. no deberias mandar eso tambien?

Comment: Lo he intentado pero me devuelve false. Voy a actualizar arriba lo que he intentado sin éxito.

Answer (score 1):

Tras mucho tiempo encontré la respuesta y era mucho más sencilla de lo que parecía. Era tan simple como poner la función original, sin usuario ni contraseña, de SetConnectionProxy() y después, en la primera navegación, meter en la url el usuario y la contraseña del proxy: [http://usuario:contraseña@url](http://usuario:contrase%C3%B1a@url), y lo he hecho así:

La conexión al proxy primero:

```
{

 public static bool SetConnectionProxy(string proxyServer)

       {

            IntPtr hInternet = InternetOpen(miniYo, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, null, null, 0);
            INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION[] Options = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION[2];

            // Set PROXY flags.
            Options[0] = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION();
            Options[0].dwOption = (int)INTERNET_PER_CONN_OptionEnum.INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS;
            Options[0].Value.dwValue = (int)INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONN_FLAGS.PROXY_TYPE_PROXY;

            // Set proxy name.
            Options[1] = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION();
            Options[1].dwOption = (int)INTERNET_PER_CONN_OptionEnum.INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_SERVER;
            Options[1].Value.pszValue = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(proxyServer);

            // Allocate a block of memory of the options.
            System.IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(Options[0]) + Marshal.SizeOf(Options[1]));
            System.IntPtr current = buffer;

            // Marshal data from a managed object to an unmanaged block of memory.
            for (int i = 0; i < Options.Length; i++)
            {
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(Options[i], current, false);
                current = (System.IntPtr)((int)current + Marshal.SizeOf(Options[i]));
            }

            // Initialize a INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST instance.
            INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST option_list = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST();

            // Point to the allocated memory.
            option_list.pOptions = buffer;

            // Return the unmanaged size of an object in bytes.
            option_list.Size = Marshal.SizeOf(option_list);

            // IntPtr.Zero means LAN connection.
            option_list.Connection = IntPtr.Zero;

            option_list.OptionCount = Options.Length;
            option_list.OptionError = 0;
            int size = Marshal.SizeOf(option_list);

            // Allocate memory for the INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST instance.
            IntPtr intptrStruct = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(size);

            // Marshal data from a managed object to an unmanaged block of memory.
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(option_list, intptrStruct, true);

            // Set internet settings.
            bool bReturn = InternetSetOption(hInternet, INTERNET_OPTION.INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION, intptrStruct, size);

            // Free the allocated memory.
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(buffer);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(intptrStruct);
            InternetCloseHandle(hInternet); //¿Esto lo cierra?

            // Throw an exception if this operation failed.
            if (!bReturn)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException(" Set Internet Option Failed!");
            }

            return bReturn;
        }

}
La primera navegación con el usuario y la contraseña, después:
{
UriBuilder uriSite = new UriBuilder(string);
                uriSite.UserName = usuario;
                uriSite.Password = contraseña;
                webBrowser.Navigate(uriSite.Uri);
}
```

Usuario y contraseña ya no son necesarios en las siguientes navegaciones.

Comment: Me alegra que lo solucionaras. Recuerda que puedes marcar como aceptada tu propia respueta. Un saludo